# Not able to install apache2-dev due to Depends, for apxs2 installation

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I'm not able to run:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-dev
```

All I get is:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This
>   may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
>   using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
>   yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
>   information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  apache2-dev :
>
> Depends: libapr1-dev but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: libaprutil1-dev but it is not going to be installed
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

Overall I want to install apxs2 to get my phpbrew running. But for apxs2 you need some packages like the `apache2-dev` installed.

Versions:
Apache2/2.4.20
Ubuntu
phpbrew 1.22.5

Already tested the following commands without success:

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get upgrade
- sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
- sudo apt-get autoclean
- sudo apt-get clean
- sudo apt-get build-dep apache2-dev
- sudo apt-get install httpd-devel
- sudo apt-get -y install apache2-dev apache2-devel
- sudo apt-get install apache2-threaded-dev
- sudo apt-get install apache-prefork-dev
- sudo apt-get install libaprutil1-dev
- sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends "apache*"
- sudo apt-get install libapr1-dev

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible via a workaround. So first of all you need `aptitude` installed to decide about the way of solving that issue. So:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

after that, run:

```
sudo aptitude install apache-dev
```

here you get:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-dev comerr-dev{a} krb5-multidev{a} libapr1-dev{ab} libaprutil1-dev{ab} libexpat1-dev{a} libgssrpc4{a} 
  libkadm5clnt-mit9{a} libkadm5srv-mit9{a} libkdb5-7{a} libldap2-dev{a} libmysqlclient-dev{a} libpcre16-3{a} libpcre3-dev{a} 
  libpcre32-3{a} libpcrecpp0{a} libpq-dev{a} libpq5{a} libsctp-dev{a} libsctp1{a} lksctp-tools{a} uuid-dev{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,304 kB of archives. After unpacking 28.5 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libaprutil1-dev : Depends: libaprutil1 (= 1.5.3-1) but 1.5.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 is installed.
 libapr1-dev : Depends: libapr1 (= 1.5.0-1) but 1.5.2-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     apache2-dev [Not Installed]                        
2)     libapr1-dev [Not Installed]                        
3)     libaprutil1-dev [Not Installed]                    

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
```

As you can see, type `n` and `Enter`. Now you get a much better solution:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Remove the following packages:                                              
1)     libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3                                                   

     Install the following packages:                                             
2)     libaprutil1-dbd-pgsql [1.5.3-1 (trusty)]                                  

     Downgrade the following packages:                                           
3)     libapr1 [1.5.2-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (now) -> 1.5.0-1 (trusty)]         
4)     libaprutil1 [1.5.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (now) -> 1.5.3-1 (trusty)]     
5)     libaprutil1-ldap [1.5.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (now) -> 1.5.3-1 (trusty)]

Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
```

Type `Y` and `Enter`. Now you get what you need:

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-ldap 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2-dev comerr-dev{a} krb5-multidev{a} libapr1-dev{a} libaprutil1-dbd-mysql{a} libaprutil1-dev{a} libexpat1-dev{a} 
  libgssrpc4{a} libkadm5clnt-mit9{a} libkadm5srv-mit9{a} libkdb5-7{a} libldap2-dev{a} libmysqlclient-dev{a} libpcre16-3{a} 
  libpcre3-dev{a} libpcre32-3{a} libpcrecpp0{a} libpq-dev{a} libpq5{a} libsctp-dev{a} libsctp1{a} lksctp-tools{a} uuid-dev{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 23 newly installed, 3 downgraded, 1 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,486 kB of archives. After unpacking 28.5 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] Y
Get: 1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main libpcre16-3 amd64 2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 [251 kB]
Get: 2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libaprutil1-ldap amd64 1.5.3-1 [8,634 B]
Get: 3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libaprutil1-dbd-mysql amd64 1.5.3-1 [12.2 kB]
Get: 4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libaprutil1 amd64 1.5.3-1 [76.4 kB]
Get: 5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libapr1 amd64 1.5.0-1 [85.1 kB]
Get: 6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main libpcre32-3 amd64 2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 [243 kB]
Get: 7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libgssrpc4 amd64 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2 [53.1 kB]
Get: 8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libkadm5clnt-mit9 amd64 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2 [36.2 kB]
Get: 9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main libpcrecpp0 amd64 2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 [149 kB]
Get: 10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libkdb5-7 amd64 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2 [36.2 kB]
Get: 11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libkadm5srv-mit9 amd64 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2 [50.4 kB]
Get: 12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libsctp1 amd64 1.0.15+dfsg-1 [9,226 B]
Get: 13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main uuid-dev amd64 2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7 [23.7 kB]
Get: 14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libsctp-dev amd64 1.0.15+dfsg-1 [64.4 kB]
Get: 15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libapr1-dev amd64 1.5.0-1 [599 kB]
Get: 16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main libpcre3-dev amd64 2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 [630 kB]
Get: 17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libldap2-dev amd64 2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8.3 [259 kB]
Get: 18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/eugenesan/ppa/ubuntu/ trusty/main comerr-dev amd64 2.1-1.42.13-1ubuntu1+20151129~eugenesan~trusty1 [38.7 kB]
Get: 19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libexpat1-dev amd64 2.1.0-4ubuntu1.3 [115 kB]
Get: 20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libpq5 amd64 9.3.13-0ubuntu0.14.04 [78.6 kB]
Get: 21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main krb5-multidev amd64 1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2 [111 kB]
Get: 22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libpq-dev amd64 9.3.13-0ubuntu0.14.04 [140 kB]
Get: 23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libmysqlclient-dev amd64 5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [865 kB]
Get: 24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libaprutil1-dev amd64 1.5.3-1 [334 kB]
Get: 25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main apache2-dev amd64 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13 [166 kB]
Get: 26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main lksctp-tools amd64 1.0.15+dfsg-1 [51.3 kB]
Fetched 4,486 kB in 2s (1,805 kB/s)     
dpkg: warning: downgrading libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 from 1.5.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 to 1.5.3-1
(Reading database ... 753970 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-ldap_1.5.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.3-1) over (1.5.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1-dbd-mysql:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-dbd-mysql_1.5.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaprutil1-dbd-mysql:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
dpkg: libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 apache2-bin depends on libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 | libaprutil1-dbd-mysql | libaprutil1-dbd-odbc | libaprutil1-dbd-pgsql | libaprutil1-dbd-freetds; however:
  Package libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 is to be removed.
  Package libaprutil1-dbd-mysql:amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package libaprutil1-dbd-odbc is not installed.
  Package libaprutil1-dbd-pgsql is not installed.
  Package libaprutil1-dbd-freetds is not installed.

(Reading database ... 753974 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 (1.5.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
dpkg: warning: downgrading libaprutil1:amd64 from 1.5.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 to 1.5.3-1
(Reading database ... 753970 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1_1.5.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaprutil1:amd64 (1.5.3-1) over (1.5.4-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
dpkg: warning: downgrading libapr1:amd64 from 1.5.2-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 to 1.5.0-1
Preparing to unpack .../libapr1_1.5.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapr1:amd64 (1.5.0-1) over (1.5.2-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgssrpc4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libgssrpc4_1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgssrpc4:amd64 (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkadm5clnt-mit9:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libkadm5clnt-mit9_1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkadm5clnt-mit9:amd64 (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkdb5-7:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libkdb5-7_1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkdb5-7:amd64 (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkadm5srv-mit9:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libkadm5srv-mit9_1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkadm5srv-mit9:amd64 (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpcre16-3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpcre16-3_2%3a8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcre16-3:amd64 (2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpcre32-3:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpcre32-3_2%3a8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcre32-3:amd64 (2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsctp1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libsctp1_1.0.15+dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsctp1:amd64 (1.0.15+dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package uuid-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../uuid-dev_2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking uuid-dev (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsctp-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libsctp-dev_1.0.15+dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsctp-dev (1.0.15+dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libapr1-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libapr1-dev_1.5.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapr1-dev (1.5.0-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libldap2-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libldap2-dev_2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libldap2-dev:amd64 (2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libexpat1-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libexpat1-dev_2.1.0-4ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libexpat1-dev:amd64 (2.1.0-4ubuntu1.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpcrecpp0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpcrecpp0_2%3a8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcrecpp0:amd64 (2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpcre3-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpcre3-dev_2%3a8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcre3-dev:amd64 (2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpq5.
Preparing to unpack .../libpq5_9.3.13-0ubuntu0.14.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpq5 (9.3.13-0ubuntu0.14.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package comerr-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../comerr-dev_2.1-1.42.13-1ubuntu1+20151129~eugenesan~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking comerr-dev (2.1-1.42.13-1ubuntu1+20151129~eugenesan~trusty1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package krb5-multidev.
Preparing to unpack .../krb5-multidev_1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking krb5-multidev (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpq-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libpq-dev_9.3.13-0ubuntu0.14.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpq-dev (9.3.13-0ubuntu0.14.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libmysqlclient-dev_5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient-dev (5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-dev_1.5.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaprutil1-dev (1.5.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package apache2-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../apache2-dev_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apache2-dev (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lksctp-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../lksctp-tools_1.0.15+dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lksctp-tools (1.0.15+dfsg-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.5) ...
Processing 2 added doc-base files...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for install-info (5.2.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Setting up libapr1:amd64 (1.5.0-1) ...
Setting up libaprutil1:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
Setting up libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
Setting up libaprutil1-dbd-mysql:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
Setting up libgssrpc4:amd64 (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2) ...
Setting up libkadm5clnt-mit9:amd64 (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2) ...
Setting up libkdb5-7:amd64 (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2) ...
Setting up libkadm5srv-mit9:amd64 (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2) ...
Setting up libpcre16-3:amd64 (2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up libpcre32-3:amd64 (2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up libsctp1:amd64 (1.0.15+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up uuid-dev (2.20.1-5.1ubuntu20.7) ...
Setting up libsctp-dev (1.0.15+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up libapr1-dev (1.5.0-1) ...
Setting up libldap2-dev:amd64 (2.4.31-1+nmu2ubuntu8.3) ...
Setting up libexpat1-dev:amd64 (2.1.0-4ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up libpcrecpp0:amd64 (2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up libpcre3-dev:amd64 (2:8.39-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1) ...
Setting up libpq5 (9.3.13-0ubuntu0.14.04) ...
Setting up comerr-dev (2.1-1.42.13-1ubuntu1+20151129~eugenesan~trusty1) ...
Setting up krb5-multidev (1.12+dfsg-2ubuntu5.2) ...
Setting up libpq-dev (9.3.13-0ubuntu0.14.04) ...
Setting up libmysqlclient-dev (5.5.50-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Setting up libaprutil1-dev (1.5.3-1) ...
Setting up apache2-dev (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.13) ...
Setting up lksctp-tools (1.0.15+dfsg-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
```

and with this `apache-dev` is installed.

Now apxs2 can be used as parameter with phpbrew.

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me. But the command should read `sudo aptitude install apache2-dev`.

Comment: I think it does not matter at all. It installs the latest apache.

Answer (score 0):

it does matter on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. sudo aptitude install apache2-dev works.